# How to specifiy --project in the "dotnet run" build step

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops

This is my build step

[image]

This is the produced log

```
2017-10-23T12:46:42.8958745Z ##[section]Starting: dotnet run Tools
2017-10-23T12:46:42.8958745Z ==============================================================================
2017-10-23T12:46:42.8958745Z Task         : .NET Core
2017-10-23T12:46:42.8958745Z Description  : Build, test and publish using dotnet core command-line.
2017-10-23T12:46:42.8958745Z Version      : 1.0.2
2017-10-23T12:46:42.8958745Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2017-10-23T12:46:42.8958745Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=832194)
2017-10-23T12:46:42.8958745Z ==============================================================================
2017-10-23T12:46:43.3968589Z [command]"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" run d:\a\1\s\Tools\Tools.csproj --configuration test
2017-10-23T12:46:43.5008554Z Couldn't find a project to run. Ensure a project exists in d:\a\1\s, or pass the path to the project using --project.
2017-10-23T12:46:43.5138548Z ##[error]Error: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe failed with return code: 1
2017-10-23T12:46:43.5138548Z ##[error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : d:\a\1\s\Tools\Tools.csproj
2017-10-23T12:46:43.5168542Z ##[section]Finishing: dotnet run Tools
```

The problem is, the project the task should run is not passed via the `--project` argument. But how can I do that with the options the build step provides?

Comment: What's the setting of Workspace mappings (Get Sources)? What's the structure of your project? (e.g. Tools.csproj in Tools folder) Provide the screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a .Net Core console app stored with the following content in a Git repo:

```
reporoot/
reporoot/Program.cs
reporoot/temp.csproj
```

to run it with the .net, provide the following arguments to the .Net Core task:

- command: run
- Projects: *.csproj
- Arguments -p temp.csproj

This is a sample output:

`2017-10-23T18:14:22.2924112Z ##[debug]C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe arg: run
2017-10-23T18:14:22.2924112Z ##[debug]C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe arg: d:\a\1\s\temp.csproj
2017-10-23T18:14:22.2924112Z ##[debug]C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe arg: -p temp.csproj
2017-10-23T18:14:22.2934125Z ##[debug]exec tool: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe
2017-10-23T18:14:22.2934125Z ##[debug]arguments:
2017-10-23T18:14:22.2934125Z ##[debug]   run
2017-10-23T18:14:22.2934125Z ##[debug]   d:\a\1\s\temp.csproj
2017-10-23T18:14:22.2934125Z ##[debug]   -p
2017-10-23T18:14:22.2934125Z ##[debug]   temp.csproj
2017-10-23T18:14:22.2943933Z [command]"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" run d:\a\1\s\temp.csproj -p temp.csproj
2017-10-23T18:14:36.1934899Z Hello World!`

Comment: Doesn't work: `[command]"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" run d:\a\1\s\Tools\Tools.csproj -p Tools.csproj --configuration test` fails with `MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist. Switch: Tools.csproj`

Comment: Note that your project is under Tools directory, the -p argument needs it too

Comment: My csproj file is under reporoot/source so my commands are

"dotnet build -p source/charttools.csproj --no-restore"
"dotnet test -p source/charttools.csproj --no-build --verbosity normal"

But I get the same error telling me there is no project in the working directory and I need to specify it